# can not add a shadow to the view, CALayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, shadow

I am adding a shadow to my view by following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds].CGPath;
}
```

However, I am getting a view with no shadow at all like below

[image]

Did I miss some points in the middle of the way.  Please advice me on this issue

Comment: I did add quart to the `Link Binary With Libraries` and I also added `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to my class..

Answer (score 3):

You need to set layer.masksToBounds to NO and clipsToBounds to YES.

```
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Nope, in the modern days, these 2 properties are equivalent and changes in one are synchronously reflected in another.

Answer (score 1):

You are not offsetting your shadow at all. 
Try:

```
self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I do `self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);` because I want to show the shadow around my view..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry all, this is my stupid mistake. The view structure I am having is

```
view(UIView) ( in white color )
    |
    |
    aView (UIView) ( in orange color )
```

what I did was to show the shadow of `view` not `aView`. Just corrected the code like below

```
(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.aView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.aView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.aView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    self.aView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    self.aView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds].CGPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

making the offset 0, will produce a nil effect on the view.

Answer (score 0):

you should make the offset have a certain value not 0. 
for example:

```
self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, -1);
```

so that there will be a shadow forming in your view.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
-(void)makeShadow
{
      self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
      self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f,3.0f);
      self.layer.shadowColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
//    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
//    layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
//    layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
}
-(void)makeCornerRadius:(CGFloat)_cornerRadius
{
   self.cornerRadius = _cornerRadius;
   [self.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
   [self.layer setCornerRadius:_cornerRadius];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that    `self.clipsToBounds = NO;`

Answer (score 0):

Your view looks unrelated to the code you provided. Be sure you are applying the shadow to the correct view, you are not masking the view to its bounds, and the colors are correct. The code below shows a working example:

```
UIView *pointView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pointLabel.frame];
pointView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pointView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
pointView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
pointView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
pointView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
pointView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:pointView.bounds].CGPath;
```